# How do I solve this logarithmic equation ln

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

How would I solve an equation like this? I need to find v.

$$a\cdot\ln{(b+v)} = -t + a\cdot\ln{(b+d)} $$

Is it possible to solve something like this using $e$ without excessive complications?

**edited because forgot to actually put v in the equatoin.

Comment: I'm assuming $a$ is acceleration and $t$ is time?  If so, the equation isn't dimensionally correct.

Comment: Sorry, added v and all other variables are constants.

Comment: Cant edit my comment so i'll correct my self not all variables are constants t is in fact time but a isn't accelaration, anyway just looking at the math of the question not the physics, want to know if tt's solveable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a\cdot\ln{(b+v)} = -t + a\cdot\ln{(b+d)}$$

Divide by $a\neq 0$ and exponentiate both sides:

$$b+v=e^{-t/a+\ln(b+d)} \implies v = (b+d)e^{-t/a}-b$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$a(\ln(b+c)-\ln(b+d))=-t$$ and if $$a\ne 0$$ we get
$$\ln\left(\frac{b+c}{b+d}\right)=-\frac{t}{a}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Can I say after that the e^(ln(b+c)/(b+d)) = e^(-t/a)

Comment: and then (b+c)/(b+d) = e^(-t/a) ?

Comment: yes this is right

Answer (score 0):

First put the natural logs together on one side and factor out the $a$:
$$ a \left[\ln (b+v) - \ln(b+d)\right] = -t$$

Now divide both sides by $a$ (we require $a\ne 0$ for this) and use the fact that $\ln X - \ln Y = \ln (X/Y)$ to get:
$$ \ln \frac{b+v}{b+d} = -\frac ta$$

Now convert this to an exponential equation.  That is, use the fact that $\ln X = Y$ is equivalent to saying $X = e^Y$:
$$ \frac{b+v}{b+d} = e^{-t/a}$$

Finally, multiply both sides by $b+d$ and then subtract $b$ from both sides.